# How to call method without oEvent

Tags: sapui5

How to call Event handler from a method of the controller?

```xml
<Button text="click" tap=".BtnTap" />
```

```js
BtnTap: function(oEvent) {
  console.log("Button Tap");
},

doSomething : function() {
  BtnTap();
},
```

I want same `BtnTap()` call from another function in the controller.
It doesn't seem to be possible to access `oEvent` from another function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle calling a function without oEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513390/how-to-handle-calling-a-function-without-oevent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not so elegant to directly to call the event handler. Maybe you can extract the logic in the event handler to another function.

```
BtnTap: function(oEvent) {    
    console.log("Button Tap");
    this.btnTapHelper();
}

btnTapHelper: function() {
    //logic here
}

doSomething : function() {
    this.btnTapHelper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually say you communicate across controllers via the eventbus. So you would catch the tap event in your direct controller and submit another event which is then caught within the other controller.

The controller which is to capture the event has something like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().subscribe('submitSomething', eventID, this.reactToSomething, this);
```

the emitter would something like this on tap:

```
eventBus.publish('submitTmpData', eventID);
```

and the aforementioned capturing controller's event handler looks something like this.

```
reactToSomething: function(type, eventid){
        ...
    },
```

You can also add custom data to your events.

Cheers
Michael